# Switch to absolute font size in ConTeXt

Tags: context

Is there a preferred/supported way to switch the current font size to an *absolute* value in ConT<sub>E</sub>Xt?

The wiki page [Font Switching](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Font_Switching) and [reference manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf) describe commands such as `\tfb` and `\tfx` which scale the font size up or down *relative* to the current size.

[`\switchtobodyfont`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/switchtobodyfont) accepts an absolute font size, but does not adjust the font size back to the desired size, as seen below:

[image: switchtobodyfont]

```
\mainlanguage[en]
\setuppapersize[letter]
\setupbodyfont[modern,12pt]
\starttext

1. Normal text (12pt)

2. {\tt \{\backslash tfb \{\backslash switchtobodyfont[12pt] normal\}\}} \longrightarrow\ {\tfb tfb{\switchtobodyfont[12pt] normal}}

3. {\tt \{\backslash tfb \{\backslash switchtobodyfont[10pt] normal\}\}} \longrightarrow\ {\tfb tfb{\switchtobodyfont[10pt] normal}}

4. {\tt \{\backslash tfb \{\backslash switchtobodyfont[8pt] normal\}\}} \longrightarrow\ {\tfb tfb{\switchtobodyfont[8pt] normal}}

\stoptext
```

In all `\switchtobodyfont[<new_font_size>]` items above, the resulting font size is *larger* than `<new_font_size>`, and most interestingly, the use of `\switchtobodyfont[12pt]` in (2) keeps the font size as-is.

Based on this observation, perhaps `\switchtobodyfont[<new_font_size>]` interprets `<new_font_size>` not as an absolute value, but in relation to `<standard_font_size>` in `\setupbodyfont[<standard_font_size>]`? That would explain the font size in item (2) not being adjusted because `12pt / 12pt = 1`, but this is only a guess...

(The example above is contrived and simplified for illustration purposes.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Could you pease explain a little more in detail which output you were expecting? To me it looks just fine...

Comment: I think you're blaming the wrong commands. `\tfb` is scaling the font with respect to the current size. Among other alternatives, you could use `\definedfont[Serif@12pt]` which, however, will only work properly with fonts for which a typescript file is available.

Comment: Thanks @Mensch. @DG' good call-out; I've elaborated the expected behavior for `\switchtobodyfont[12pt]` in an edit above. @Jairo A. del Rio I'm very new to ConTeXt and not familiar with the details, but is there an alternative which _only_ accepts the desired size and applies it to the _current_ font face/style without explicitly specifying it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\fullrestoreglobalbodyfont`. In the MWE below I defined a command to combine this setting with the selection of a new font size. This setting, unlike the name might suggest, is local to the group.

```
\mainlanguage[en]
\setuppapersize[letter]
\setupbodyfont[modern,12pt]
\define[1]\globalfsize{\fullrestoreglobalbodyfont\switchtobodyfont[#1]}
\starttext
1. Normal text (12pt)

2. {\tt \{\backslash tfb \{\backslash switchtobodyfont[12pt]\}\}} \longrightarrow\ {\tfb tfb{\globalfsize{12pt} Normal} still tfb} Normal

3. {\tt \{\backslash tfb \{\backslash switchtobodyfont[10pt]\}\}} \longrightarrow\ {\tfb tfb{\globalfsize{10pt} Normal} still tfb} Normal

4. {\tt \{\backslash tfb \{\backslash switchtobodyfont[8pt]\}\}} \longrightarrow\ {\tfb tfb{\globalfsize{8pt} Normal} still tfb} Normal

\stoptext
```

[image]